# Cookies only working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have been working on a project, and in the project, I've decided to make a mobile version of the website.

What I want to do is to set a cookie that temporarily (for 20 min) "disables" a welcome message that will be viewed when the page loads.

The problem with the cookie is that it's not working on either Chrome or Opera, but it works on Firefox.

I don't know what the problem is. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm kind of new to web development.

Here's the code:

**Welcome function:**

```
function welcome1 () {
        $('.message').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay((i++) * 2000).fadeTo(700, 1);
            $(this).delay(1400).fadeOut(300);
        }),
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.solar-body').each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(400, 1); 
            })
        }, 5000);
    }
```

**Cookie:**

```
    // c_name = cookie name
    // c_value = cookie value
    // ex_min = expiration in minutes
    function setCookie(c_name, c_value, ex_min) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (ex_min * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + "; " + expires;
    }
```

**OnLoad Function:**

```
function welcomeMessage() {
        var lastVisitedCookieName = 'last-visited';
        if (!document.cookie.contains(lastVisitedCookieName)) {
            welcome1();
            setCookie(lastVisitedCookieName, "1", 20);
        }
        else if (document.cookie.contains(lastVisitedCookieName)) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.solar-body').each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay((i++) * 200).fadeTo(400, 1); 
                })
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the URL in the address bar look like? If it starts with `file://`, then that’s the problem. You need to run a local server (so the URL becomes e.g. `http://localhost:8000/`) to test your website properly.

---

**Update:** The problem might be you’re using `String.prototype.contains`. It has been renamed to `String.prototype.includes` in the spec, and only Firefox still supports the old form. Use [a polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.includes), or use `.indexOf()` and `> -1` instead (that way it works in all browsers, including older ones).

P.S. Since you’re using jQuery anyway, and to make it easier to work with cookies, why not use [the jQuery cookie plugin](https://mths.be/cookie)?

Comment: It's hosted on godaddy.com. Not a local file. The URL is [oursolarsystem.co/mobile/solar_system.html](http://www.oursolarsystem.co/mobile/solar_system.html)

Comment: So I should update my if-statement from `if (!document.cookie.contains(lastVisitedCookieName))` to `if (!document.cookie.includes(lastVisitedCookieName))`, right?

Comment: @Maze, if you only care about modern browsers that implement the ES6 spec, then yes. But it wouldn’t work in Firefox (unless you use the polyfill), so it’s probably not what you want. Use the polyfill, or use `document.cookie.indexOf(lastVisitedCookieName) > -1`, as described in my answer.